# Safari takes +200MB memory on every page reload when Web Inspector is open

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, safari, web-inspector

Safari takes +200MB memory on every page reload when Web Inspector is open. On every site.

I opened google and Web Inspector.

And reload the page 12-16 times:
[image: And reload the page 12-16 times]

Information about memory usage in Web Inspector:
[image: Information about memory usage in Web Inspector]

Why Safari takes so much memory? Why Safari doesn't clear memory? How can I stop it?